# How to output foreach inside echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to output inside echo foreach to output the terms that belong to this post. How can i do this? The code I wrote is not working.

```js
$cur_terms = get_the_terms( $ajaxposts->post->ID, 'cities' ); 

 echo '<div class="speaker-city">
        '. foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ): .'
         <p>
            '. echo $cur_term->name .'      
         </p>
         '.endforeach; .' 
       </div>';
```

Comment: Make them all separate statements. You cannot have a foreach statement inside a string concatenation.

Comment: Could you show a code example of how this can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use foreach block and print inside the block

```
$cur_terms = get_the_terms( $ajaxposts->post->ID, 'cities' ); 

echo '<div class="speaker-city">';
foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term )
{
    echo'<p>'. $cur_term->name .'</p>';
}
echo'</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to echo separately. And echo within the foreach loop.

```
$cur_terms = get_the_terms( $ajaxposts->post->ID, 'cities' ); 

echo '<div class="speaker-city">';
foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
    echo '<p>{$cur_term->name}</p>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I have an error - syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ',' or ';'